# Transfer Text from Word to Excel in next row available

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working on 'Word Document' where a text is selected and converted into variable let say CCC.

I want to transfer this CCC to 'Excel Workbook' Sheet1 in next empty row.

I am trying following code but it seem not doing anything:

```
Set CCC= Selection.Range.PARAGRAPHS(1).Range
Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
MyXL.Visible = True
Set eXwb = MyXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\WEBD\LIST.xlsm")
With eXwb.Application
        .Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = CCC
End With
```

Before that I was using following code which was working fine and I want to improve it so:

```
 With eXwb.Application
     .Sheets("Sheet1").Select
     .ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CCC
     .ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
 End With
```

Comment: I think that should be `CCC.Text`, given `CCC` is a Word Object Range.

Comment: Why do you enter the variable as a FormulaR1C1 into the cell? You may want to try and use more distinct steps instead of putting everything into one line of code. Then you can step through the code and see what is what.

Comment: When you create excel programatically it is not visible by default. Add MyXL.visible = True after your Set myXL line. Also It should be With eXwb there shouldn't be an application there.

Comment: @L42 I tried `CCC.Text` still nothing happened.
@teylyn then what should I use in replace of `FormulaR1C1`?
@HarassedDad used `eXwb.visible= True` still the same

Comment: @Muhammad Bilal: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1075849-transfer-text-word-excel-next-row-available.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @macropod I posted here first waited enough for the answer then re-posted it on Mrexcel because got problem and I need to solve it as soon as possible.

Comment: That doesn't mean you're exempt from the common courtesy of letting those who read the post here or elsewhere know that you've cross-posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that you need to address as your code as posted will not compile.

1. Insert 'option explicit' at the start of the module.  This will force you to declare your variables before you use them.
2. In the VBA IDE go Tools.Options.Editor and ensure that all boxes in 'Code Settings' are ticked.  This will ensure that any errors you make in your code usage is highlighted before you get to run the code.
3. CreateObject("Excel.Application") results in late binding.  You probably want early binding to get the best functionality from intellisense.  So in the VBA IDE go Tools.References and ensure that the checkbox for 'Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library' is ticked.

You can then replace

```
Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

with

```
Set MyXL = New Excel.Application
```

4. ExWB.Application

Is referring back to the parent excel application and is not needed.  Just use ExWB.  By referring back to the parent application any further code after 'Application.' will be referring to the activeworkbook of the application which may not be the Workbook you are working in.

5. Sheet1 does not exist (although you've since posted and shown it is a name of 'Sheet1').  The sheets and Worksheets collections are indexed using parentheses and either an integer or the worksheet/sheet name as the index.

   set my_ws = ExWb.WorkSheets(1)

or

```
set my_ws = ExWb.WorkSheets("Sheet1")
```

You will notice I've changed the Sheet1 reference to Worksheets. (You should also lookup the difference between Worksheets and Sheets as the two are not the same in Excel) The reason I made this change is that the Sheets object does not support the .Rows property.  So excel, with intellisense enabled, will not let you enter the code

```
ExWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
```

as nothing will pop up when you type the . after Sheets("Sheet1").

5. Rows.Count

This is a non valid statement in the Word Application.  It can only be used in the context of an Excel Application.  Because you are working in Word any unqualified reference to Application is to the Word Application. You would need to say

```
my_count = MyXL.Rows.Count
```

Even so, the code above references the ActiveWorksheet which may or may not be the sheet you are referencing with .Sheets("Sheet1"). Change

```
.Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
```

to

```
.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.count, 1)
```

Note the '.' in front of the Rows which means you are in effect saying

```
.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Cells(ExWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,1)
```

i.e. correctly specifying the worksheet with which you want to work.

6. FormulaR1C1

This implies that the text you are getting from the Word document is an excel formula and that you are entering a formula in your cell.  Your post is implying you just want to insert the text. Therefore you may need you final line changing to

.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = CCC.Text

7 The F1 key

In the VBA IDE, putting the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1 will bring up the MS help page for that keyword.

There's a lot to digest in the above but it should help clarify why your code isn't working.

Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: I worked on each of yours suggestion and come up with this  `.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(eXwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = CCC.Text` which is working just fine. now I want to know that is it possible to use 1 row and then move forward because this code skipping first Row.

Comment: I think you need to understand better what the results of the Rows and End methods produce.  F1 my friend.  When you understand better you will either be able to resolve the issue yourself or ask a further question which is more specific.